# Delete rows in matrix containing certain elements (python)

Tags: python, list, lambda

The following problem I have, might be very trivial for a more advanced python programmer, but I -- as a python beginner -- can't figure out the problem.

I just want to delete a row from a 2D-list, if it matches a certain condition --- in my case, if the row contains a certain character. I wanted to do it in a more functional, python way, rather than looping over all list items. Therefore, my attempt was

```
    alist = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    map(lambda ele : (if 2 in ele: tmp3.remove(ele)), alist)
```

which should just delete the first row, because it contains a "2". But I just get an error "invalid syntax" and I don't know why!

(I also came across some solution which uses dataframes from the pandas package, but as I'm learning python, I want to avoid pandas at this stage ;) )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an `if` statement in a lambda. You could use the more clearer *list comprehension*:

```
alist = [row for row in alist if 2 not in row]
```

This also has the advantage of iterating through the list once, as opposed to using `map` and `list.remove`, although you get a new list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove elements from a list, you need `filter` instead of `map` which is often used for transformation and doesn't change the length of the list:

```
alist = [[1,2],[3,4]]
filter(lambda ele : 2 not in ele, alist) 
# [[3, 4]]
```